# Changing the delimitor for search results with multiple values

Tags: sharepoint, search, sharepoint-2010, delimiter

I have a metadata property in SharePoint 2010 which returns multiple values. The multiple values are separated by space. But I have some items which has more than one word. So differentiating between two results and one result with two words is not possible.

Can some one tell how to change the default delimiter from space to some special character.

Thanks.